# Shift pinescript series by one

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Suppose I have a pinescript series `current` that looks like this;

```
current = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]
```

I want to shift this series backward by 1. The `shifted` variable will look like this;

shifted = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]

The last sample of `shifted` will always be `0`.

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it next. If you just output a plot like this

```
plot(barstate.islast ? 0 : current, offset = -1)
```